# Why isn't the ResultSet picking up my ClientId field? MySQL, Spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Hi I'm looking to populate a Client object from a MySQL database with the following fields:
    `Id;ApellidoPaterno;ApellidoMaterno;Nombre; Telefono; and Username`.

The following is the create table command I used:

```
'Cliente', 
    'CREATE TABLE `cliente` (
    `ClientId` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `ApellidoPaterno` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `ApellidoMaterno` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Nombre` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Telefono` mediumtext,
    `Username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ClientId`)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

And my Connection class:

```
package me.jmll.utm.config;

import java.sql.*;

public class Conexion{ 

public Connection getConexion(){  
    Connection con = null;      
    try {  
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(  
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/miscelanialabety","root","Patito01"); 
        return con;  
    }
    catch(Exception e){ 
        try {throw e;} 
    catch (Exception e1) { e1.printStackTrace();}}
    return con;
    }  
}
```

And my getClientes() method:

```
@Override
        public List<Cliente> getClientes() {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Cliente";

            try {
                conexion = new Conexion().getConexion();
                PreparedStatement ps = conexion.prepareStatement(sql);
                Cliente cliente = null;
                List<Cliente> listaClientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    cliente = new Cliente(
                        rs.getInt(1),
                        rs.getString("ApellidoPaterno"),
                        rs.getString("ApellidoMaterno"),
                        rs.getString("Nombre"),
                        rs.getLong("Telefono"),
                        rs.getString("Username")
                    );
                    listaClientes.add(cliente);
                }
                rs.close();
                ps.close();
                return listaClientes;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                if (conexion != null) {
                    try { conexion.close();}
                    catch (SQLException e) {}
                }
            }
        }
```

On the line `rs.getInt(1)`, I've tried `rs.getInt("ClientId")`, to no avail, and I've tried specifying the exact fields to return in the query.

The resulting list contains all the fields requested from the db, except from "ClientId", Which is the most important! Where am I going wrong?

Edit for comment: The data in the table is the following:

```
ID  AppelidoPaterno AppelidoMaterno Telefono Username

1   Osorio  Marquez Rafael  2227355623  RafaelOsorioMarquez
2   Hernandez   Carrillo    Rodrigo 2227128907  RodrigoHernandezCarrillo
3   Fernandez   Hernandez   Juan    2226770934  JuanFernandezHernandez
4   Gomez   Trujillo    Diego   2220200435  DiegoGomezTrujillo
5   Figueroa    Lopez   Roberto 2221106286  RobertoFigueroaLopez
6   Almeyda Martinez    Luis    2224376232  LuisAlmeydaMartinez
7   Lozano  Jimenez Cesar   2222338905  CesarLozanoJimenez
8   Reyes   Franco  Julio   2225205878  JulioReyesFranco
9   Peralta Perez   Carlos  2224783388  CarlosPeraltaPerez
15  Osorio  Carrillo    Gabriela    9981159756  GabrielaOsorioCarrillo
```

Edit2: Cliente class:

```
package me.jmll.utm.model;

public class Cliente
{
    int Id;
    String ApellidoPaterno;
    String ApellidoMaterno;
    String Nombre;
    long Telefono;
    String Username;
    //getter and setter methods

    public Cliente(int Id, String ApellidoPaterno,String ApellidoMaterno, 
                        String Nombre,long Telefono) {
        this.ApellidoPaterno = ApellidoPaterno;
        this.ApellidoMaterno = ApellidoMaterno;
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
        this.Telefono = Telefono;
    }

    public Cliente(int Id, String ApellidoPaterno,String ApellidoMaterno, 
            String Nombre,long Telefono, String Username) {
            this.ApellidoPaterno = ApellidoPaterno;
            this.ApellidoMaterno = ApellidoMaterno;
            this.Nombre = Nombre;
            this.Telefono = Telefono;
            this.Username = Username;
}

    public Cliente() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setApellidoPaterno(String apellidoPaterno) {
       this.ApellidoPaterno = apellidoPaterno;
    }

    public String getApellidoPaterno() {
       return ApellidoPaterno;
    }

    public void setApellidoMaterno(String apellidoMaterno) {
        this.ApellidoMaterno = apellidoMaterno;
     }

    public String getApellidoMaterno() {
        return ApellidoMaterno;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.Nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setTelefono(long telefono) {
        this.Telefono = telefono;
    }

    public long getTelefono() {
        return Telefono;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return Username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.Username = username;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the minimal data present in the database ? Does the data exist in the database ?

Comment: Hi, yeah the data is present in the database, and I've included the columns in an edit. Sorry for the late reply!

Comment: Everything seems okay, add the code for `Cliente` class ?

Comment: Added. Thanks for your help! Does it have anything to do with this field being the only auto_increment field in the table? Or if it has a foreign key from another table linked to it?

Comment: Look at the answer below, constructor issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Cliente` class constructor, you have missed out setting the `id` field, so set it as `this.id =id` as shown in the below code:

```
public class Cliente {

        public Cliente(int Id, String ApellidoPaterno,String ApellidoMaterno, 
                String Nombre,long Telefono) {
            this.Id = Id; //this is missed out
            //set other fields as is
        }

        public Cliente(int Id, String ApellidoPaterno,String ApellidoMaterno, 
                String Nombre,long Telefono, String Username) {
            this.Id = Id; //this is missed out
            //set other fields as is
        }

        //add other code
    }
```